# AJAX Return ParseError with plain text of php file

Tags: php, json, ajax, parse-error, php-parse-error

I am doing an ajax request to a php file to return a certain value.
I did some console logs to check the results:

readyState: 4
Status: 200
responseText: php file in plain text
error: parseError

Can anyone help me?

request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "popup.php" ,
    success : function(data) { 
        $("#stock").html("€" + data);
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }
});
```

php file:

```
<?php
    $array = array();
    $url = 'url_name';
    $parameters = [
        'start' => '4',
        'limit' => '1',
        'convert' => 'EUR'
    ];

    $headers = [
        'Accepts: application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: apikey',
        'Content=Type: application/json',
    ];
    $qs = http_build_query($parameters);
    $request = "{$url}?{$qs}";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $request,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
    $response_data = json_decode($response);    
    $res_data = $response_data->value;

    echo json_encode($res_data);

?>
```

Comment: `'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: apikey',` looks wrong, but it could just be your obfiscation

Comment: Have you checked what your PHP script is returning? If not, you can do so by opening the Network tab in the Developer toolbar and clicking on the AJAX request, then selecting Response in it.

Comment: @El_Vanja it shows the php file in plain text as a response

Comment: Are you sending this AJAX to the same page?

Comment: No, the ajax request is at popup.js and the url used for the ajax request is popup.php

Comment: But is `popup.js` included in the `popup.php` or are they completely separate?

Comment: The only other idea I have is that maybe your server isn't processing `.php` files at all and so your request just fetches the file contents.

Comment: In the end I got it to work without using any php, just wrote it in javascript and got it to work, thanks for your replies!